# How to find a Element in a Grid that is in the same row and the next colum?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In my application I use a Grid. The Grid has some rows and 5 colums:

```
|a|b|c|d|e|
-----------
|f|g|h|i|j|
-----------
|k|l|m|n|o|
```

Now i have a reference to c, h and m.

Whats the easiest way to get a reference to d, i and n?

Comment: Do you have references to the data items at c, h, and m?  Or references to the cells? If all you have is references to the data items, then the only way you'll be able to get d, i, and n is by searching the grid.

Comment: I have a reference to the element in the cell. I was wondering if it is possible to get all element of the same row and then just get the following element (if they are ordered by columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to enumerate over the child items collection of the Grid instance and then interrogate the Grid.Row and Grid.Column dependancy properties of each child to find the ones of interest. There is no shortcut method on the Grid to find the ones of interest quicker.